# untar the directory structure only

Tags: bash, unix, tar

Is it possible to extract only the directory structure from a tar-archive without extracting the files?

I tried to use

```
tar tvpf archive.tar | nawk '/.*\/$/{ print $NF }' | tar -xpf archive.tar --no-recursion -T -
```

All directories are shown with a trailing /. So with nawk I print out only these which have these / at the end of the line. The problem is, that tar -T - does not accept pathnames seperated by line. The other whitespaces separetes the filenames so it does not work for pathes which contains spaces. Any idea?

It is not a solution to untar all, then remove the files, then tar-copy the directory to the target, although it is possible. I want to create a solution without temporary files. bash solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, I came across an answer for something similar a while ago.

```sh
tar -tf file.tar | grep -v '/$' | sed 's/ /\\ /g' > excluded_files ; tar xfX file.tar excluded_files ; rm -f excluded_files
```

The first part looks in the tar, piping output to grep to grab only filenames, these are sent to a temporary file. Then extract the tar, excluding the excluded files, and finally remove the temporary file.

Edit: added sed to remove escape spaces in paths.

**Update**

As suggested in the comments, this is also acheivable with no temporary file and a process substitution. Cheers Walter A. Much cleaner.

```sh
tar xfX file.tar <(tar -tf file.tar | grep -v '/$' | sed 's/ /\\ /g')
```

Comment: You can avoid the temp file with process substitution:
`tar xfX file.tar  <(tar -tf file.tar | grep -v '/$' | sed 's/ /\\ /g')`

Answer (score -1):

If you can use a bit of C code, you could take [libarchive/examples/untar.c](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/blob/master/examples/untar.c) and add a single check.

```
if (archive_entry_filetype(entry) != AE_IFDIR) continue;
```